# Expirar sesión y redirigir a otra página. Evitar retroceder y avanzar a la misma página

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

tengo una página web desarrollada en ASP .NET Webforms. la cual consta de una página de ingreso, donde se debe ingresar un código y una contraseña, donde posteriormente me ingresa a un formulario con los datos del cliente.

Primero, me gustaría saber como hacer para que al ingresar al formulario, el usuario al retroceder al login no pueda volver al formulario con el botón avanzar del navegador.

Lo otro es como hacer que en unos 2 minutos si el usuario sigue en la página del formulario retrocederlo al login.

Este es el login:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: esto lo puedes manejar del lado del cliente, estas usando alguna libreria de javascript o solo javascript puro?

Comment: No conozco mucho al respecto, pero no se hace con cookies? Le pones un tiempo de expirar de 2 minutos, o algo así...

Comment: Gracias por responder chicos, estoy trabajando con Js puro, sé que por medio del Web.Config se puede validar el tiempo de expirar session y dentro de un archivo llamado global.asax puedes crear una session con session_start y session_end, pero lo que no logro es hacer que al expirar la session te mande al login

Answer (score 0):

para cerrar la sesión, podrías hacerlo con javascript usando setTimeout, por ejemplo:

```
var timer = setTimeout(CerrarSession, 120000);

function CerrarSession(){
/**
 * llamar a la acción para crear sesión en la aplicación web
 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a lo que es retroceder en la web mediante el navegador, la forma es hacerlo con Javascript (Si no querés agregar lógica fuerte al backend). Te copio una función JS que utilicé para esto con exito. Si la agregás en un layout que utilices en las páginas donde lo necesitás, va a evitar el backbutton del navegador en todas estas. Lo agregás dentro del body y listo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableBackButton() {
        window.history.forward();
    }
    setTimeout("DisableBackButton()", 0);
    window.onunload = function () {
        null
    };
</script>
```